# PHP XMLReader skips at large XML file

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I try to proceed a large xml file (about 1.5 GB) with about 3 million items with PHP XMLReader.
But the script stops randomly between 2,3 and 2,6 million items without an error.

There is no time or memory limit.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This is the code:

```
$Reader = new XMLReader();
$Reader->open('file.xml', NULL, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);

$count = 0;

while ($Reader->read()) {
    if ($Reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $Reader->name == 'file') {
        $outerXml = $Reader->readOuterXml();
        $count ++;
        echo $count . "\r\n";
    }
}

echo 'end';
```

XMLReader seems to have some kind of restriction. I already tried the LIBXML_PARSEHUGE option but with no success.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
It seems to be a problem with http curl via SSH, even with --max-time option set.
It works with when running directly through the PHP parser.

Comment: Are you running this from CLI? Or from a web SAPI?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, I run this with an http curl via SSH.